# python subprocess.check_call not parsing properly

Tags: python

Folks,
  I am trying to call an executable from this code, and its not working properly for some reason, (python 2.6)

```
subprocess.check_call(
 ['fpm', '-s', 'dir', '-t', 'rpm', '-n', 'name', '-v', 'rpmversion',
  '--prefix=/opt/', '--rpm-auto-add-directories', 'target'], shell=True)
```

output:

```
{:message=>"Missing required -s flag. What package source did you want?", :level=>:warn, :timestamp=>"2013-12-05T17:37:29.   %6N+0000"}
{:message=>"Missing required -t flag. What package output did you want?", :level=>:warn, :timestamp=>"2013-12-05T17:37:29.   %6N+0000"}
{:message=>"No parameters given. You need to pass additional command arguments so that I know what you want to build packages from. For example, for '-s dir' you would pass a list of files and directories. For '-s gem' you would pass a one or more gems to package from. As a full example, this will make an rpm of the 'json' rubygem: `fpm -s gem -t rpm json`", :level=>:warn, :timestamp=>"2013-12-05T17:37:29.   %6N+0000"}

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['fpm', '-s', 'dir', '-t', 'rpm', '-n', 'name', '-v', 'rpmversion', '--prefix=/opt/', '--rpm-auto-add-directories', 'target']' returned non-zero exit status 1
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Running the same command from cli works perfectly.  Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to not use `shell=True` if it is not needed (since it can be a security risk when used with user-supplied arguments -- see the [Warning in the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)). In this case, you could use

```
subprocess.check_call(
 ['fpm', '-s', 'dir', '-t', 'rpm', '-n', 'name', '-v', 'rpmversion',
  '--prefix=/opt/', '--rpm-auto-add-directories', 'target'])
```

---

When `shell=True`, you should pass a string as the first argument:

```
subprocess.check_call(
    'fpm -s dir -t rpm -n name -v rpmversion --prefix=/opt/ --rpm-auto-add-directories target', shell=True)
```